# Some of the products below do not have all the required options error on cart page when add configuareble product to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, cart, error

[[image]][[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrR4B.png)[image]

I have some configurable products in my store which have required options Decorations and size for configuaration and another option "Desired Delivery Date" from custom options of configuarable product.

When i add this product into cart and go to cart page it is displaying error "Some of the products below do not have all the required options."

But also all rewuired options which i selected displaying on cart page.

Please give me some solution.

Comment: Please provide screenshots of product options in backend, cart page and product view Page in frontend.

Comment: Also the Product Page Configuration screenshot and the Product view page on bakend

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this issue and resolved successfully. This issue occurs due to custom options.

To resolve this issue, check the associated product's custom options and remove that if there is any exist.

In my case, There is an custom options exist in associated products.

Answer (score 0):

Still facing this issue here...

Configurable products with *required* custom options don't pass the validation in **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract::checkProductBuyState()** function, which seems to be a Magento bug

**UPDATE**
My mistake. As [zed Blackbeard](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/28515/zed-blackbeard) has pointed, error was being fired because some simple products had custom options (in my case, it was difficult to see, as backoffice does not show any custom option in simple products, but I have confirmed that after a DB review)

Answer (score 0):

This is the stupidest fix ever, but you can do this if you feel brave.  It will fix it up quick.  In fact, you might investigate truncating the whole sales_flat_quote_item_option table.

```
delete
FROM magento.sales_flat_quote_item_option
where product_id = SomeProductId
```

Those flat tables can be the devil.

Comment: Hello again, myself. Thanks for helping me out.